# Erro ao compilar projeto.BuildGradle

Tags: android, build

Desinstalei o android studio e instalei novamente e agora não consigo compilar o meu projeto.

A seguinte mensagem aparece:

```
 Error:Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.
```

**build.gradle**:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
    }
}


allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "contactorganizer.introcode.or.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.2'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Existe um erro no `buildscript`

Tente da seguinte forma:

```
buildscript {
   repositories {
      jcenter()
   }
   dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
   }
}
```

Adicione `classpath` antes de declarar a `dependencies`.

Comment: Ainda nada amigo, continua o mesmo erro.

Comment: Que estranho. Consigo reproduzir aqui perfeitamente... São apenas estas informações que tem em seu gradle?

Comment: Isso mesmo amigo, com a modificação sugerida já inclusa, são todas as informações do gradle.